# Проставить индексы абзацев текстов в pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Всем привет, интересует такая задача:
Имеется на руках csv файл с текстами в каждой ячейке. Тексты разбиваются таким образом по абзацам, что каждый абзац попадает в отдельную ячейку. Необходимо добавить два столбца в датафрейм: в первом будет номер текста, а во втором номер абзаца в тексте.
К примеру имеем текст foo и bar:

```
| Абзац     | Индекс_Текста     | Индекс_Абзаца     |
|-------    |---------------    |---------------    |
| foo_0     | 0                 | 0                 |
| foo_1     | 0                 | 1                 |
| foo_2     | 0                 | 2                 |
| foo_3     | 0                 | 3                 |
| bar_0     | 1                 | 0                 |
| bar_1     | 1                 | 1                 |
| bar_2     | 1                 | 2                 |
```

С задачей как разбить по абзацам и сделать индексы_текста я справился, так что предположим что у нас есть некий датафрейм с 1 и 2 столбцами. Как сделать индекс абзаца?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cumcount расставитт последовательные номера в каждой группе

```
исходный df

   Абзац  Индекс_Текста
0  foo_0              0
1  foo_1              0
2  foo_2              0
3  foo_3              0
4  bar_0              1
5  bar_1              1
6  bar_2              1


df['Индекс_Абзаца'] = df.groupby('Индекс_Текста').cumcount()

   Абзац  Индекс_Текста  Индекс_Абзаца
0  foo_0              0              0
1  foo_1              0              1
2  foo_2              0              2
3  foo_3              0              3
4  bar_0              1              0
5  bar_1              1              1
6  bar_2              1              2
```

Comment: О дааа, спасибо! я не знал что так можно! супер.